# syntax for creating variable out of command with apostrophe in it

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, syntax

NOOB level: horrible at syntax and regular expressions and BASH programming in general but learning and studying for the Lin+

I'd like to run this script but it doesn't like my syntax apparently.

Just to test that the variable is being created properly I am echoing the output, but later, the variable will be manipulated to determine which static IP file to be concatted into /etc/network/interfaces and which list of network host IPs to scan with NMAP, grab logs from, etc.

here is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Script to grab the System IP and Gateway Addresses and use them to
# determine which other scripts to run my network scans with

ip=$(ip a | grep 'global[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}')
gateway=$('route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}')

echo $ip
echo $gateway

done
```

Here is the output:

```bsh
./test: 11: ./test: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

When I put "" in place of () like this:

```bsh
ip=$"ip a | grep 'global[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}'"
gateway=$"'route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}'"
```

Here is the output:

```bsh
$ip a | grep 'global[   ]' | awk '{print }'
$'route -n | grep 'UG[  ]' | awk '{print }'
```

If i remove the $ the output is the same. It just prints the apostrophed command and doesn't output the result of said command.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have an unnecessary `'` character in front of your route command. This leads to an unterminated quoted string error message as you have an odd number of apostrophes.

Change

```
gateway=$('route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}')
```

to

```
gateway=$(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}')
```

The syntax highlighting provided by the code formatting in Stack Exchange is actually helpful in noticing this. The quoted strings are shown as red while unquoted are black.

Comment: this did fix it. simple mistake. thank you.

Comment: They're often the easiest to miss! Good luck with your Lin+